# program stop working and exit

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, readfile

i am doing read file in c++ and this is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <climits>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int row=0;
int col=0;
ifstream inputFile;
int arr[16][5];

    inputFile.open("hdtt4req.txt");

if(inputFile.is_open()) {
        inputFile >> arr[row][col];
        for (row = 0; row < 16; row++) {
            for (col = 0; col < 5; col++) {
                cout <<"hi"; //arr[row][col];
                cout << endl;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and this is the file that i want to read:

```
1 2 2 1 2 
2 1 1 1 2 
3 1 1 1 6 
4 2 2 3 2 
1 2 5 1 2 
2 0 4 3 2 
3 1 2 1 0 
4 2 2 1 2 
1 2 1 1 2 
2 0 0 5 1 
3 2 1 4 1 
4 6 1 2 1 
1 3 1 2 1 
2 1 4 1 4 
3 3 3 2 1 
4 2 0 1 1
```

after i compile , i get this kind of result. can anyone tell me what is the error ? thanks

Comment: When i run the for loop to retrieve the data that i store in the 2d array, i get some very strange data. Is there ant logical error ? how come will have this kind of data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

row and col start start undefined, so the statement `inputFile >> arr[row][col];` will give you undefined behavior. Make sure you set these values to zero before performing any operations

```
row = col = 0;
```

Comment: hi thanks . but when i want to display the item that i have read nad put into the array, it give me many strange number . how come ? is there any wrong ?

Comment: your program has more issues that need to be worked out. Email me your program code and we can get it working from there, it would clog the comments if i were to attempt to help you here. You can find my email by clicking on my profile page, i'd be glad to help

Comment: read the last part of my comment before, you can find it on my profile screen by clicking my name.

Comment: @Need4Sleep , i really didnt see any email on your profile page.

Comment: @Eric Gmercer015@gmail.com